# prerender.io is loading very slow

Tags: prerender

I have installed prerender with headless chrome. It all works well except that it takes 20 seconds to render the content. My website is loading fast (2-3 seconds max). Even on google page speed, I get 90/100 score. But prerender return code 200 only after 20 seconds. Does anyone know what could be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

A 20 second load time either means you have window.prerenderReady set to false, there is a pending network request that never completes, or something is constantly sending network requests so that the Prerender browser never thinks the page is done rendering....so it times out at 20 seconds.

Feel free to share a URL so we can help test and see which of those issues is causing the 20 second load time.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I'm using Firebase Firestore with snapshot listeners (listens for database updates), do you think that's causing the issue? I don't exactly know what firebase is doing, but I can assume they set up a websocket.

Comment: Can you send us an email at support@prerender.io with the URL you are seeing issues with? We'd be happy to take a look!